# Create Angular2 Table Header with *ngFor loop

Tags: html, angular, primeng

So, my problem is so basic but i cant solve it.

I'm trying to create dynamic table header with *ngFor.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
        <th>Entry Warehouse</th>
        <th colspan="2" *ngFor="let data of datas">
          SomeText
        </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <th>More Text</th>
       <div *ngFor="let data of datas">
         <th>A little text again</th>
         <th>A little text again</th>
       </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Anyway, this solution suicide themself at that point. If datas length more than 1, div tag is underscoring th tag in same cell.
If i try another solution like this;

```html
<table>
  <tr>
        <th>Entry Warehouse</th>
        <th colspan="2" *ngFor="let data of datas">
          SomeText
        </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <th>More Text</th>
       <th *ngFor="let data of datas">A little text again</th>
       <th *ngFor="let data of datas">A little text again</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

it looks like works but actually not. Because at this time the next th tag doesnt start before the previous loop ends.

Comment: Can you add your JSON data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In angular 2+ you can use`<ng-container>` tags

```
<ng-conatiner *ngFor="let i of items">
<th>i</th>
</ng-conatiner>
```